# SQLite character encoding via shell select

Tags: encoding, sqlite

I have the following problem. I'm using SQLite3 to store some code table information.
There is a text file that contains all the rows I need. I've trimmed it down to one to make things easier.
The codetbls.txt file contains the one row I want insert into the table codetbls.
Using notepad++ to view the file contents shows the following:

codetbls.txt (Encoding: UTF-8)

```
1A|Frequency|Fréquence
```

I've created the following table:

```
create table codetbls (
    id char(2) COLLATE NOCASE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name_eng varchar(50) COLLATE NOCASE,
    name_fr varchar(50) COLLATE NOCASE
);
```

I then execute the following:

```
.read codetbls.txt codetbls
```

Now, when I run a select, I see the following:

```
select * from codetbls;

id name_eng  name_fr
--+---------+----------
1A|Frequency|Fr├®quence
```

I don't understand why it doesn't show properly.
If I execute an insert statement with 'é' using the shell prompt, it shows up correctly. However using the `.read` command doesn't seem to work.

Based on other suggestions, I have tried the following:

```
- changed datatype to 'text'
- changed character encoding to UTF-8 without BOM
```

I don't know why it doesn't show. Any help?

Comment: What does `file codetbls.txt` say?

Comment: `1A|Frequency|Fréquence` on one line.

Comment: Are you using Windows? The Windows command prompt does not handle UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: Yes, win7. How come with I run an insert statement using `cmd` and using alt codes (Alt+0233) to insert an 'é' works and shows up correctly when I run a select. However, reading it from a file doesn't?

Comment: The command prompt is *consistently* buggy; its own keyboard input will be displayed as is. However, it is not UTF-8.